# Different formats of OpenIDs

Tags: php, openid

stackoverflow,

I am experimenting with implementing OpenID in my existing site. I have looked at [Plaxo's article](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe) on this very subject and I'm a mite confused about something.

I am using [this PHP OpenID library](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/). I have some code running, and I am getting a unique OpenID back.

From myopenid.com, I am getting an id that looks like https://myusername.myopenid.com/

But from Yahoo and Google, I am getting an ID that much more cryptic, e.g. https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlbp1cxujdJWDnpx72xVROOw-5V_WzIDZA

Are Google's and Yahoo's "gibberish" ids unique for every login user, i.e. is this the value that I use to tie in with existing user on my web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openid_identifier is a URL. It may be readable or may be cryptic, it's up to OP to decide. And yes, canonicalized URL is what you use as a key.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. So the ID I get back from Google is static for each user, i.e. it isn't session based or anything?

Comment: Yes, the idea of OpenID is that it's persistent and asserts user's identity, so it can't possibly be session-specific.

Comment: Although there is an important thing to know about Google's /accouns/o8/id identifiers, which is that they vary with the `openid.realm`.  See http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/web/the-most-important-technical-issue-in-using-the-google-accounts-api?pli=1